# Flash and autofocus control parameter deprecated how to replace with Camera 2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

In this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            builder = builder.setFocusMode(
                    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
        }

        mCameraSource = builder
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .build();
```

The lines

```
Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
```

Are both deprecated due to newer Camera2 API. Unfortunately I haven't understood how I could update with current version without break the code.

Comment: You are welcome to continue using the original `Camera` API. All of that API was marked as deprecated, because Google likes marking things as deprecated. However, you have no choice but to use the original `Camera` API on Android 4.4 and older anyway. Or, if you prefer, use a third-party library for wrapping the camera APIs (e.g., [CameraKit-Android](https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android), [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat)).

Comment: @CommonsWare I prefer remove all deprecated code to improve compatibility with future OS versions.

Comment: Well, then you need to get rid of *all* uses of the `Camera` API in your code. Presumably, your code is using far more than those two constants, as otherwise those two constants would be pointless, since they only have meaning with the `Camera` API. `android.hardware.camera2` has focus mode and flash mode options as part of `CameraCharacteristics`.